# Why does my Cypress test fail to find an element in a modal when running on GitHub Actions, but not locally?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, cypress, github-actions

I have a custom Cypress command cy.el(selector) that I use to find an element within a modal on my Vue app. Here's the code for the command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('el', (selector) => {
  return cy
    .get('ion-modal:not(.overlay-hidden)', { timeout: 50000 })
    .first({ timeout: 50000 })
    .find('.ion-page:not(.ion-page-hidden)', { timeout: 50000 })
    .first({ timeout: 50000 })
    .find(selector, { timeout: 50000 })
    .should('be.exist', { timeout: 50000 })
})
```

When I run this command in my local Cypress test environment, it works as expected and finds the element I'm looking for. Similarly, my login test also passes on GitHub Actions.

However, when I run another test that uses the cy.el(selector) command on GitHub Actions, the test fails with the error message "Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element".

I've confirmed that the modal is present in the DOM on GitHub Actions, and I've tried increasing the timeout for the command to 60 seconds, but the test still fails.

Here's the relevant part of my GitHub Actions YAML file:

```
    name: cypress
on: [push]
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Cypress - pre-analyses test
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          start: npm run test:e2e:chrome
          browser: chrome
          screenshotOnRunFailure: true
          screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots'
          wait-on: http://localhost:8080/
          config-file: cypress.config.ts
          spec: "tests/e2e/**/*"
        env:
          CYPRESS_baseUrl: http://localhost:8080/
          VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL }}
          VUE_APP_MAP_KEY: ${{ secrets.VUE_APP_MAP_KEY }}
          VUE_APP_SEGMENT_KEY: ${{ secrets.VUE_APP_SEGMENT_KEY }}
          VUE_APP_SENTRY_DSN: ${{ secrets.VUE_APP_SENTRY_DSN }}
          CYPRESS_USER_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_USER_EMAIL }}
          CYPRESS_USER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_USER_PASSWORD }}
```

My simulation test workflow:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import scenarios from '../support/pre-analysis-scenario-var.ts'

describe('Test simulation', { includeShadowDom: true }, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login()
  })

  it('simulation flow', () => {
    cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 50000 }).should('include', 'page/home')
    cy.wrap(scenarios).each((scenario) => {
      cy.wait(2000)
      cy.get('[data-cy="home-page"]').should('be.exist', { timeout: 10000 }).first().click({ force: true })
      cy.wait(2000)
      cy.get('[data-cy="new-simulation"]')
        .should('be.exist', { timeout: 10000 })
        .first()
        .wait(600)
        .shadow()
        .find('button')
        .first()
        .click({ force: true })

      // step 0
      cy.wait(4000)
      cy.el('[data-cy="address"] input')
      cy.el('[data-cy="address"] input').click().type(scenario.address, { delay: 100 })
      cy.get('div.pac-item').first().click({ force: true })
      cy.el('[data-cy="submit"]').shadow().find('button').should('not.be.disabled').click({ force: true })

      // step 1
      cy.wait(800)
      cy.el(`[data-cy="property_ownership_type"] ion-item[data-cy="${scenario.property_ownership_type}"]`).click()
      cy.el('[data-cy="submit"]').shadow().find('button').should('not.be.disabled').click({ force: true })

      // step 2
      cy.wait(800)
      cy.el('[data-cy="surface_area"] input').click().type(scenario.surface_area)
      cy.el('[data-cy="outdoor_area"] input').click().type(scenario.outdoor_area)
      cy.el('[data-cy="number_of_rooms"] input').click().type(scenario.number_of_rooms)
      cy.el('[data-cy="construction_period"]').click().wait(200)
      cy.get('ion-select-popover ion-item').contains(scenario.construction_period).click()

      if (scenario.storey !== null) {
        cy.el('[data-cy="storey"]').click().wait(200)
        cy.get('ion-select-popover ion-item').contains(scenario.storey).click()
      }
      cy.el('[data-cy="submit"]').shadow().find('button').should('not.be.disabled').click({ force: true })

      // ...

      // step 12
      cy.wait(800)
      cy.el('[data-cy="submit"]').shadow().find('button').should('not.be.disabled').click({ force: true })
    })
  })
})
```

Cypress sometimes can pass the first cy.el(selector), but can fail on the next one.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have to show all of the workflow up until (including) the step you're currently showing as an answer depends on it. Please [edit] and also reduce to the minimal example that triggers your problem  (e.g. on a branch for trouble-shooting only).

Comment: @hakre Thanks for your response. I have already edited my question and added the full reduced code of my test workflow.

Comment: Perhaps a misunderstanding, with the name "workflow" I was referring to what you describe as "GitHub Actions YAML file". The cypress part doesn't hurt, but the Github Actions workflow configuration is what is crucial.